# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-utils.version' (java)

Tags: android, firebase

I get this error when I run the application when I connect with firebase

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, try to add this line in **build.gradle** file: **exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'**, then Run 'app'

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}
```

If error continue occur: **'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'**, keep adding exclude **'META-INF/INDEX.LIST**':

```
 android {
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        }
    }
```